# Site home page loads slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagespeed

We have an amazing site for the most part due javascript. [x-tech.am](http://x-tech.am)

We use plugins queryloader2.js, modernizr-2.6.2.min.js, fitvids.js, fittext.js and more.
Consequently site loading slowly especially when the increase the portfolio.

Can you advise us how to increase the download site without losing these javascript effects?

Comment: Please describe what you did to find a solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing lazyload would definitely decrease load time

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Edit:
http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fx-tech.am%2F

I know it doesn't always gives the best ideas but enabling gzip and Caching the images using localStorage if they are not frequently updated would also help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your javascript.  It's the amount of images you are downloading on each page load.

Answer (score 0):

When I see on network tab: 223 requests  ❘  6.7 MB transferred. I think it's kinda big number.

You have big images, I mean in KB per image:
- Dimensions: 450 × 320;
- File size: 107 KB

Try to use RIOT ( http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/ ) it cuts images headers, you dont need them in web. Maybe make some sprites to reduce page requests.

Lazy load will also do the job: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload